# Javascript - Loop through object and use key/value to perform text replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am working on a function that receives an object organised in this manner:
{"oldID1":"newID1", "oldID2":"newID2" , … }

This information is to be fed into another function which will perform a string replace of oldID1 with newID1, oldID2 with newID2 etc,  inside a textarea containing these ID's.

This initial object originally comes from a series of sorting operations, such that the object keys represent a list's original order, and the object values represent the newly sorted order. So, for example, I would be confronted with an object looking like this:

```
{
"1":"3",
"2":"1",
"3":"2",
"4":"4"
}
```

Where the intent was to move item 3 to the top of the list. As a result, for the text in the separate textarea, 1 should be replaced by 3, 2 by 1 and 3 by 2.

When I try to iterate the object and perform the replace, I run into problems because some text gets replaced more than once. So '1' gets replaced by '3', but then later on gets replaced by '2'.

Here is the code I'm using to loop through that object:

```
$.each(the_object, function(key, value){   
      replace_text(key,value);
});

function replace_text(old_id, new_id){
    var textarea        = $("#the_textarea");
    var str             = textarea.val();
    var replace_regex   = new RegExp("<pic_"+old_id+">");
    str = str.replace(replace_regex, '<pic_'+new_id+'>');
    the_textarea.val(str);
}
```

I should emphasise that the sorting process is independent of the text replacing. I am simply concerned in finding the best way to perform that text replace given the object I have.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you object containing the IDs are named `idObj` and it is available in the closure of the function passed to replace, I guess this should work:

```
var textarea = $('#the_textarea');
textarea.val(function(i,str){
  return str.replace(/<pic_(.*?)>/g,
     function(m,n){ 
       return '<pic_' + (idObj[n] || n) + '>';
     });
});
```

The n variable here will contain the old index. I see that the properties of idObj is named after the old indices, thus the new index can be retrieved like this `var newIndex = idObj['oldIndex];` and the function returns  for any given old index.

Comment: @Jørgen: Two notes: A) This will replace IDs that are not in the object with `undefined`. B) Just use a function argument to `.val()` and return a new value. See my solution.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak. I editet my answer about the undefined. However, I don't see how passing a function argument to val() makes it less complicated?

Comment: Nevermind, I was a little confused about the concat of the keys.

Comment: @Jørgen Your solution with `|| n` is better. +1 Deleted mine as it is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obvious.

for key "1"  '1' gets replaced by '3' and for the key "3"  '3' gets replaced by '2'

So you can do something like this. In function

```
var replace_regex   = new RegExp("<pic_"+old_id+">");
str = str.replace(replace_regex, '<pic_N'+new_id+'>');
```

then after loop

```
str = str.replace(/<pic_N/g, '<pic_');
```

see a demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/cJn6w/4/

.